# How to get between and overall R2 from plm FE regression with stargazer?

Tags: r, regression, panel, stargazer, plm

Disclaimer: This question is extremely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61081199/7929151) one I asked two days ago - but now it relates to the implementation of between and overall R2 in `stargazer()` output not in `summary()` as before.

Is there a way to get `plm()` to calculate between R2 and overall R2 for me and include them in the `stargazer()` output?

To clarify what I mean with between, overall, and within R2 see this answer on [StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79734).

My understanding is that plm only calculates within R2. 
I am running a Twoways effects Within Model.

```
library(plm)
library(stargazer)

# Create some random data
set.seed(1) 
x=rnorm(100); fe=rep(rnorm(10),each=10); id=rep(1:10,each=10); ti=rep(1:10,10); e=rnorm(100)
y=x+fe+e

data=data.frame(y,x,id,ti)

# Get plm within R2
reg=plm(y~x,model="within",index=c("id","ti"), effect = "twoways", data=data) 
stargazer(reg)
```

**I now also want to include between and overall R2 in the `stargazer()` output. How can I do that?**

To make it explicit what I mean with between and overall R2:

```
# Pooled Version (overall R2)
reg1=lm(y~x)
summary(reg1)$r.squared

# Between R2
y.means=tapply(y,id,mean)[id]
x.means=tapply(x,id,mean)[id]

reg2=lm(y.means~x.means)
summary(reg2)$r.squared
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in `stargazer`, you can use the `add.lines()` argument. **However**, this adds the lines to the beginning of the summary stats section and there is no way to alter this without messing with the source code, which is beastly. I much prefer [`huxtable`](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/), which provides a grammar of table building and is much more extensible and customizable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plm)
library(huxtable)

# Create some random data
set.seed(1) 
x=rnorm(100); fe=rep(rnorm(10),each=10); id=rep(1:10,each=10); ti=rep(1:10,10); e=rnorm(100)
y=x+fe+e

data=data.frame(y,x,id,ti)

# Get plm within R2
reg=plm(y~x,model="within",index=c("id","ti"), effect = "twoways", data=data) 
stargazer(reg, type = "text", 
          add.lines = list(c("Overall R2", round(r.squared(reg, model = "pooled"), 3)),
                           c("Between R2", round(r.squared(update(reg, effect = "individual", model = "between")), 3))))
#> 
#> ========================================
#>                  Dependent variable:    
#>              ---------------------------
#>                           y             
#> ----------------------------------------
#> x                     1.128***          
#>                        (0.113)          
#>                                         
#> ----------------------------------------
#> Overall R2              0.337           
#> Between R2              0.174           
#> Observations             100            
#> R2                      0.554           
#> Adjusted R2             0.448           
#> F Statistic    99.483*** (df = 1; 80)   
#> ========================================
#> Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01


# I prefer huxreg, which is much more customizable!

# Create a data frame of the R2 values
r2s <- tibble(
  name = c("Overall R2", "Between R2"), 
  value = c(r.squared(reg, model = "pooled"), 
            r.squared(update(reg, effect = "individual", model = "between")))) 

tab <- huxreg(reg) %>% 
  # Add new R2 values
  add_rows(hux(r2s), after = 4)

# Rename R2 
tab[7, 1] <- "Within R2"

tab %>% huxtable::print_screen()
#> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>                                    (1)           
#>                         ─────────────────────────
#>   x                                   1.128 ***  
#>                                      (0.113)     
#>                         ─────────────────────────
#>   N                                 100          
#>   Overall R2                          0.337      
#>   Between R2                          0.174      
#>   Within R2                           0.554      
#> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>   *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.        
#> 
#> Column names: names, model1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>